# exclude one file from css module and generate webpack asset separately

Tags: javascript, webpack

I already have webpack setup for css modules, however I need to  create a file to override a third party style. So that css file should be loaded as normal css. 
So I excluded that file from css rule and created new rule for that file as below

```
 {
    test: /chat.css/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          config: {
            path: path.resolve(root, 'buildTools/webpack'),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /chat.css/,
    use: [
      ...(process.env.USE_SSR === 'true'
        ? [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader]
        : [
            {
              loader: 'cache-loader',
            },
            'style-loader',
          ]),
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          minimize: true,
          localIdentName: '[folder]--[name]--[local]--[hash:base64:2]',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          config: {
            path: path.resolve(root, 'buildTools/webpack'),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Also using plugin

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash:6].css',
}),
```

in html.js we already have

```
cssAssets.push(
  <React.Fragment key="styles-fragment">
    <script key="styles-js" defer src={assets.styles.js} crossOrigin="anonymous" />
    {assets.styles.css && <link key="styles-css" href={assets.styles.css} rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

how can I make sure the chat.css is generated and what would be the generated assest name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) to generate a separate chunk for that particular CSS

Comment: Please check your output folder for the css files. It might be named with some number follwed by 6 digit hash and css extension